# Can't read file included as a script in angular.json

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to include the Google Maps clustering script in my Angular project. I have tried all of the usual suggestions, such as adding a `<script>` link to `index.html`, but so far, nothing is working.

I am getting a confusing error message when I try to include

```
https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclustererplus/dist/index.min.js
```

as a script in the `angular.json` file. According to the error output,

> An unhandled exception occurred: Script file https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclustererplus/dist/index.min.js does not exist.

The file does exist though: the link can be clicked to verify this.

From what I've read, the `scripts` element in `angular.json` should be able to include external scripts like this. What might be going wrong here? Is there a setting that needs to change?

Comment: When webpack generates bundle, it doesn't make any http request, it just collects files from project folder. So instead of url, you should add this script to your project and provide path to it

Comment: That has done the trick. If you add it as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Add it in your index.html

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclustererplus/dist/index.min.js"></script>
```

And it will work.